# Invertible matrices and row equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra

We have that $A$ and $B$ are $m\times n$ matrices, which are row equivalent. If we also have that $CA=B$, how to prove that $C$ is invertible?

Comment: It's not true in general: take $A$ and $B$ to be the zero matrix - then $C$ can be anything. In general, it depends upon the rank of $A$ and the dimensions $m,n$.

Comment: Maybe you mean that you need to prove that there EXISTS such an invertible $C$? If so, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You probably want to show that the matrix $C$ is a product of [elementary matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix) (that is, it is a matrix that does the elementary row operations on $A$ to get to $B$).

Answer (score 3):

Not true. Take $ A = \pmatrix{a & a &a \cr b&b&b\cr 0 &0&0\cr}\quad B=
\pmatrix{b&b&b\cr a & a &a \cr  0 &0&0\cr}.$ The (non-singular) permutation matrix $P$ can interchange first two rows and so they are row equivalent.
Now define $C$ to be the matrix obtained from $P$ changing the last row to be the zero row. Then $CA=B$ is still true but $C$ is not invertible.